# Spring MVC i18n <spring:message> gives JasperException : No message found under code

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, tomcat7

I am building a project using **spring mvc 3.1 jars**, after configuring i18n folder, tomcat is throwing me the following exception  :

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code **'label.title'** for locale 'en_US'.

I have tried adding the i18n folder to classpath in eclipse(Juno), placed messages*.properties files under **WEB-INF/i18n, WEB-INF/classes/i18n**, WEB-INF/classes, WEB-INF/lib, WEB-INF/ but to no use.

**spring-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <annotation-driven />
    <resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"
        mapping="/resources/**" />
    <default-servlet-handler />
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hoe.spring.controller" />
    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" />

    </interceptors>
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages, WEB-INF/i18n/application"
        p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"  p:fileEncodings="UTF-8"
    p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
        id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />
</beans:beans>
```

**messages.properties**

```
label.title=Contact_Manager
label.firstname=First_Name
label.lastname=Last_Name
label.email=Email
label.telephone=Telephone
```

**page.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<spring:message code=**"label.title"** var="cName"/>


label.addcontact=Add_Contact
label.menu=Menu
```

What am I missing ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have placed the files under resources/i18n folder.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the files under `resources/i18n` folder of your eclipse and then use `p:basenames="classpath:i18n/messages"`.

Comment: I have tried all the above solution but in vain, none of them work.

Comment: Please post latest details like, actual path of the properties file under your tomcat server, properties file names and the updated application context xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <bean id="messageSource"     class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
                        <list>
                                <value>locale.messages</value>
                                <value>locale.validation.messages</value>
                                <value>locale.email.messages</value>
                        </list>
     </property>
   </bean>
```

And put the property files under locale folder(same as package structure)
If it is maven/gradle project the locale folder comes under resource folder
locale.validation.message => locale/validation/messages_en_US.properties

Comment: <beans:bean class = "org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
  id="messageSource" p:basenames="locale.messages, locale.validation.messages, locale.email.messages"

Comment: placed messages_en_US.properties file under WEB-INF/classes/locale/validations/messages directory. Getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the message.properties file name to messages_en_US.properties

Comment: I have this files(messages_en_US.properties, messages_en_IN.properties, messages.properties, application_en_US.properties, application.properties) too under folder WEB-INF/i18n/

Comment: Did you tried the above method i have specified. That one is working for me

Comment: Yes, I have tried your options but I am getting same error. I feel its a classpath problem, here I am running the tomcat server from eclipse IDE. I have manually set the classpath (to messages folder) in eclipse. Do I have to do anything more ?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with same problem and what I realized is that messages_{}.properties must be in classpath. so, you do not need to mention basename property value "classpath:messages". Instead just mention "**messages**". here is my full configuration.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />       
</bean>


<!--  allow localization through cookie and add interceptor to allow changes to locale -->

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
     <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>     
     </bean>          
</mvc:interceptors>
```